# How do I configure a displaylink USB monitor?

Tags: 11.10, usb, monitor, displaylink

I have seen many pieces but not a comprehensive guide to fix what must be a very common problem, particularly in Ubuntu 11.10 where there is no xorg.conf file.  Is there an easy how-to somewhere (for Linux newbies like me)to get this done.  The other pieces I've seen require a fair amount of Linux ability to make them work.  Even better would be to make Ubuntu automatically detect these types of monitors.

I have a green screen and the drivers installed.  I just can't see a picture on my Doublesight USB monitor.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This may help you get it going.

**Displaylink Doublesight DS-90U monitor working**

1) Install dependencies required to build displaylink X server...

```
apt-get install xinit xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-dev xfonts-base libusb-dev xorg-dev git-core build-essential
```

2) Downloaded and fixed source for xserver-xorg-video-displaylink from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/0.3-0ubuntu4/+files/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink_0.3.orig.tar.gz) and extract the source code.

```
tar xvfz xserver-xorg-video-displaylink_0.3.orig.tar.gz
cd xf86-video-displaylink
```

Edit `src/displaylink.c`

```
#graphical
gedit src/displaylink.c

#command line
nano src/displaylink.c
```

comment (add a # to the front) out the following lines...

```
//#include "xf86Resources.h"
//#include "xf86RAC.h"
//      pScrn->racMemFlags = RAC_FB | RAC_COLORMAP | RAC_CURSOR | RAC_VIEWPORT;
//      pScrn->racIoFlags = RAC_FB | RAC_COLORMAP | RAC_CURSOR | RAC_VIEWPORT;
//      xf86CrtcScreenInit (pScreen);`
```

3) build and install

```
./configure && make && make install
sudo cp  /usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/displaylink_drv.so /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/
```

4) create /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         0  "DisplayLinkScreen" 0 0
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Driver      "displaylink"
    Option      "fbdev" "/dev/fb0"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DisplayLinkMonitor"
    # DS-90U is 1024x600 9-inch monitor - remove or change the DisplaySize for other devices
    DisplaySize  190 115
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "DisplayLinkScreen"
    Device      "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Monitor     "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection
```

5) Plug in the Displaylink monitor into a USB port (screen should go green)

6) Reboot or restart X

[source](http://forum.doozan.com/read.php?2,2073)

[instructions](http://forum.doozan.com/read.php?2,2073)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the procedure described above and I get these errors, can someone aimder me please?

> `./configure && make && make install
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for mawk... mawk
>   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
>   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
>   checking for gcc... gcc
>   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>   checking for suffix of executables... 
>   checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
>   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>   checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
>   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
>   checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
>   checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
>   checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
>   checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
>   checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
>   checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
>   checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
>   checking whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
>   checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
>   checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
>   checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
>   checking for objdump... objdump
>   checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
>   checking for ar... ar
>   checking for strip... strip
>   checking for ranlib... ranlib
>   checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
>   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
>   checking for ANSI C header files... yes
>   checking for sys/types.h... yes
>   checking for sys/stat.h... yes
>   checking for stdlib.h... yes
>   checking for string.h... yes
>   checking for memory.h... yes
>   checking for strings.h... yes
>   checking for inttypes.h... yes
>   checking for stdint.h... yes
>   checking for unistd.h... yes
>   checking for dlfcn.h... yes
>   checking for objdir... .libs
>   checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
>   checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
>   checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
>   checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
>   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
>   checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
>   checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
>   checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
>   checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
>   checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
>   checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
>   checking whether to build static libraries... no
>   checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
>   checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
>   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
>   checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
>   checking if RANDR is defined... yes
>   checking if RENDER is defined... yes
>   checking if XV is defined... yes
>   checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
>   checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
>   checking for XORG... yes
>   checking whether xf86ConfigIsaEntity is declared... no
>   checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
>   configure: creating ./config.status
>   config.status: creating Makefile
>   config.status: creating src/Makefile
>   config.status: creating config.h
>   config.status: config.h is unchanged
>   config.status: executing depfiles commands
>   config.status: executing libtool commands
>   make  all-recursive
>   make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/Téléchargements/xf86-video-displaylink'
>   Making all in src
>   make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/Téléchargements/xf86-video-displaylink/src'
>   /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/xorg -I/usr/include/X11/dri -g -O2 -MT displaylink.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/displaylink.Tpo -c -o displaylink.lo displaylink.c
>   libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -fvisibility=hidden -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/xorg -I/usr/include/X11/dri -g -O2 -MT displaylink.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/displaylink.Tpo -c displaylink.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/displaylink.o
>   displaylink.c:42:22: fatal error: mibstore.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
>   compilation terminated.
>   Makefile:302: recipe for target 'displaylink.lo' failed
>   make[2]: *** [displaylink.lo] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Téléchargements/xf86-video-displaylink/src'
>   Makefile:274: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Téléchargements/xf86-video-displaylink'
>   Makefile:204: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2`
>   
>   Have a great day.
>   Thanks